# Footer Icons Not Lining Up In Position

Tags: html, css, footer

I can't seem to get my social media icons to line up top to bottom with the accompanying words. I am looking for any suggestions on how I might be able to go about this? I've tried `display: block`, etc, but I can't seem to get it to work. I think if I could get it to line up top to bottom I could figure the rest out.

Here's a fiddle with all the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/o4aajsmu/

Edit: here's a pic of what's going on right now

[image]

Comment: The problem is you are setting block display on `.socialmediaicons` which is wrong and must be set on `.socialmediaicons > a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understanding correctly, you're overthinking it.  Why wouldn't you put all of your anchor tags in the same div and then use `display:inline-block` on the text anchor tags?  Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4aajsmu/2/).

```
<div class="socialmedia">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/yourstorybookmemory/"><img class="social" src="assets/facebook.png"></a>
    <a class="socialText" href="https://www.facebook.com/yourstorybookmemory/"><p>Storybook Memories</p></a><br/>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/yourstorybookmemory/"><img class="social" src="assets/instagram.png"></a>
    <a class="socialText" href="https://www.instagram.com/yourstorybookmemory/"><p>yourstorybookmemory</p></a><br/>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/sbvideography"><img class="social" src="assets/twitter.png"></a>
    <a class="socialText" href="https://twitter.com/sbvideography"><p>@sbvideography</p></a><br/>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcMVbKyDIJN0Ht-6VjDiFKA"><img class="social" src="assets/youtube.png"></a>
    <a class="socialText" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcMVbKyDIJN0Ht-6VjDiFKA"><p>Storybook Memories</p></a><br/>
    <a href="mailto:inquiries@yourstorybookmemory.com"><img class="social" src="assets/mail.png"></a>
    <a class="socialText" href="mailto:inquiries@yourstorybookmemory.com"><p>inquiries@yourstorybookmemory.com</p></a><br/>
</div>
```

```
.socialText{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I was just overthinking it. Now I'm hitting another snag though, it seems that doing that makes everything extremely spaced apart (or at least farther spaced apart than I want it). `margin: 0;` doesn't seem to do anything. Any ideas on that by chance? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @BJohnson that's the margin on the `<p>` tags inside of the anchor tags.  Set it to 0 for those and they'll be closer together.

Comment: Thanks a ton for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you want the icons at the bottom of the entire area?

If so, here's a couple of things. 1) `clear: all` doesn't exist (its `both`)

You should move the social icons div after the right hand column and add `clear: left` to the social icons div. Here's an updated fiddle

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o4aajsmu/3/)

```css
.footer {
background-color: #5c0e13;
color: white;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
}

.favicon, .footernav, .socialmedia, .socialmediaicons {
  float: left;
}

.favicon {
 margin-left: 1%;
 margin-top: 1%;
 margin-right: 1%;
}

.footernav a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 transition: .3s color;
}

.footernav a:hover {
 color: #db1421;
}

.socialmedia {
 margin-left: 40%;
  float: right;
}

.social {
 width: 20px;
}

.socialmedia a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 transition: .3s color;
}

.socialmedia a:hover {
 color: #db1421;
}

.socialmediaicons {
 clear: left;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
  <div class="footer">
   <div class="favicon">
    <a href="index.html"><img id="favicon" src="assets/favicon.png"></a>
   </div>
   <div class="footernav">
    <a href="index.html"><p>Home</p></a>
    <a href="ourteam.html"><p>Our Team</p></a>
    <a href="weddings.html"><p>Weddings</p></a>
    <a href="events.html"><p>Events</p></a>
    <a href="contact.html"><p>Contact</p></a>
   </div>
   <div class="socialmedia">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/yourstorybookmemory/"><p>Storybook Memories</p></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/yourstorybookmemory/"><p>yourstorybookmemory</p></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/sbvideography"><p>@sbvideography</p></a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcMVbKyDIJN0Ht-6VjDiFKA"><p>Storybook Memories</p></a>
    <a href="mailto:inquiries@yourstorybookmemory.com"><p>inquiries@yourstorybookmemory.com</p></a>
   </div>
      <div class="socialmediaicons">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/yourstorybookmemory/"><img class="social" src="assets/facebook.png"></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/yourstorybookmemory/"><img class="social" src="assets/instagram.png"></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/sbvideography"><img class="social" src="assets/twitter.png"></a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcMVbKyDIJN0Ht-6VjDiFKA"><img class="social" src="assets/youtube.png"></a>
    <a href="mailto:inquiries@yourstorybookmemory.com"><img class="social" src="assets/mail.png"></a>
   </div>
  </div>
```